# keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: node0.cer (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, cassandra, centos7, cassandra-3.0

I want to prepare server certificates for development in cassandra for client-to-node encryption, but encounter the below problem while running commands:

I am following these links to setup:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureSSLClientToNode.html
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureSSLCertificates.html

When I am running the below command:

```
keytool -export -alias cassandra -file node0.cer -keystore cassandra.keystore
```

I get this error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: cassandra.keystore
```

And when running below command:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias node0 -file node0.cer -keystore truststore.node0
```

Getting this error:

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: node0.cer (No such file or directory) java.io.FileNotFoundException: node0.cer (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1037)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:368)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:361)
```

My operating system is RS-Centos-7.

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that you are trying to export the public part of the certificate to a separate file, after you generated the key.

So for the first command

```
keytool -export -alias cassandra -file node0.cer -keystore cassandra.keystore
```

the -keystore parameter will get the keystore created with the command

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias node0 -validity 36500 -keystore keystore.node0
```

which is **keystore.node0**.

The second error is normal since you didn't generate the node0.cer file at the previous step.

Further explanation:

the first step is to generate the key and save it to a keystore. This is accomplished with

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias node0 -validity 36500 -keystore keystore.node0
```

This command generates a private/public key pair and saves it into the keystore keystore.node0 using alias node0.

The second command which is 
    keytool -export -alias cassandra -file node0.cer -keystore cassandra.keystore

should export a certificate, but there some **wrong** parameters in it. **The correct command (correlated with the above command) is**:

```
keytool -export -alias node0 -file node0.cer -keystore keystore.node0
```

After this one you should have a node0.cer that you can use further.

Basically for enabling SSL between Cassandra nodes, you are doing the following:

- create a keystore containing a private - public key pair for each of your nodes
- create a trustore containing the certificates for each node in the cluster
- change cassandra.yaml file on each node in order to specify the keystore for that node and the trustore.
- restart cassandra.

For simplicity you could have the same trustore that would contain all the certificates for all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: what do you mean by this answer, can you please check it again? i am running this command keytool -export -alias cassandra -file node0.cer -keystore cassandra.keystore and getting error.

Comment: 3 years on they still haven't fixed their docs. Thanks a million